# What kind of list are arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Probably a silly question, but I was wondering what implementation is behind arrays in JavaScript? Are they SLL (Singly Linked List) or DLL (Doubly Linked List) or something different?

Comment: Depends on the JS engine, but also on how an array is used. Assigning a property to an array may prevent an engine from using a more optimal data structure, for example. There are various articles about JS engine implementations and the kind of optimizations they perform. Keep in mind that these engines are actively being developed, so the implementation details will change over time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really tell, it can vary between implementations (V8, Rhino, etc.), it depends on what the current compiler's developer preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the browser. Why does this matter?

Could be just a hash table.

And yes - it was a silly question

Comment: Doesn't matter, just my curiosity.

Comment: It's not a total silly question - the underlying implementation affects (for example) whether array lookups are O(1), and whether operations that delete an element (that isn't the last element) such as `array.shift()` are O(n) or not.

Comment: @Alnitak - Surely Javascript is dealing with quite smallish data structures as it is for a web page.

Comment: Not necessarily - I've used JS arrays to hold tens of thousands of data points

Comment: @EdHeal pretty well, in my experience

Comment: Please could you give me a link - I would love to see this in action. Anyway a full scan compared with a hash lookup - how much slower would it be on a average computer

Comment: It's on the UI for a commercial visualisation product belonging to a previous employer, so I don't have access any more.   Either way, full scans are _always_ slower because of things like CPU caches, and a good array implementation will just use contiguous memory for its elements so that they can be indexed directly O(1)

Comment: I know a full scan will be slower. And a hash will be quicker. But for small data structures the difference is not a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array is just simply Object.

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.

From [MDN - array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Edit
As the comment of @Alnitak, the above is nothing about *implementation*. The implementation of Object in JS depends on the Javascript engine.

Comment: that says nothing about the _implementation_

Comment: @Alnitak, I agree with you. But in the question, the author mentions "SLL (Singly Linked List) or DLL (Doubly Linked List)", I guess that he(or she) just doesn't know JS Array is just Object. If he knows that, he won't guess that the implementation of Object would be some Linked List.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from V8 `object.h`:

```
// The JSArray describes JavaScript Arrays
//  Such an array can be in one of two modes:
//    - fast, backing storage is a FixedArray and length <= elements.length();
//       Please note: push and pop can be used to grow and shrink the array.
//    - slow, backing storage is a HashTable with numbers as keys.
class JSArray: public JSObject {
```

So in V8, it can be in the best case an C++ array allocated in the heap or a HashTable implementation, it depends on the interpreter and its optimization processes.

Comment: Hi Evan, it's suppose to be an answer for the main question.